# Setting TextView to new string?

Tags: java, android

I used the layout resource editor to modify the main.xml layout file to add a second
TextView control to my app. by default, its set to something like @+id/TextView01. How do I Set the text attribute of the TextView control to my newly created String resource? I tried going into main.xml and just editing the android:text to point to the name of my new string, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you define your strings inside resources/strings/values.xml 
and you can reference them using "@string/name_of_string" syntax in your layouts.

android:text="@string/name_of_string"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. That's what I tried doing. I added     <string name="rules">Random text bla bla</string> to strings.xml and then added <TextView android:text="@string/rules" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView> Did I make some basic mistake?